# Query a queried dataset (joint dataset) in birt

Tags: birt

Can we query a joint dataset in birt which is a result of a query. If yes, how ?

For example, I have a joint dataset named "Data Set 1" result of two simple queries. Can we query this "Data Set 1"  ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot query the result of a query (and a joint data set is a result of a join query).

However you can filter your results leading you to the same result like a query if you want to reduce your result set.

[image: filter results]